# How do I add color to individual geom points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point, scale-color-manual

[image]

###### Current Code:

```
ggplot(compare, aes(x=specificity, y=false_positives)) + 
  geom_jitter(height=.02, color=specificity) +
  scale_discrete_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "violet"))
```

> Error in manual_scale(aesthetics, values, breaks, ...) :
> argument "aesthetics" is missing, with no default

Comment: If we had data we could check to see if it was a missing aes call in geom_jitter.

Comment: you want to **map** values to the colour **`aesthetic`**, so you gotta tell ggplot like this: `geom_jitter(aes(color = specifity), ...)`.

Comment: Based on what your data looks like, your row-names are more meaningful. I suggest making them a "real column", and using that column as the target of `color=`. Perhaps `df$method <- rownames(df); ggplot(df, aes(..., color=method)) + ...` (very similar to what I_O suggested).

Comment: @r2evans I did this. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x=specificity, y=false_positives, color= factor(specificity))) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter()) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#8800FF")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(specificity = c(0.9, 0.87, 0.89, 0.91), false_positives = c(0.4, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.4)), row.names = c("Logistic", "Probit", "KNN", "Naive"
), class = "data.frame")
```